# Rails selected field not showing up on the form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, select, tags

This could be the dumbest question on SO but I can't figure the problem out.
I'm using an old version of Rails 2.3.3 for a project and I am displaying a form using jQuery Dialog. The form has a select box which i am rendering like this.

`<%= f.select :recurr_frequency, [["Daily", "Daily"], ["Weekly","Weely"], ["Monthly", "Monthly"]], {:selected => "Daily", :value => "Daily"} %>`

I see that the html (*when viewed in the javascript console*) to display the selected attribute as expected but the form on the browser does not show this.

I am completely clueless if this is a browser issue (*but i can't view this in any browser*) or am i doing something wrong with Rails.

So when I submit the form without selecting anything from the drop down the default selected value never gets passed to the server. Would really really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1):

This sound like a non-closed tag issue...

If you got something like this in your resulting HTML code

```
<input type="text" name="whatever" id="whatever" /
<select id="..." name="...>
  <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
  ...
</select>
```

your select statement doesn't get rendered, cause the input tag before isn't closed.
It has nothing to do with Rails itself but it can happen easily in views if you're writing
HTML without the rails helpers...

Check you sourcecode before the select tag for non-closed tags..

Hope this helps!

Comment: Checked for non-closed tags. The fields work when selected but only the default value is never passed when the user doesn't explicitly select an option. I don't have any prompt or blank value in place either.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you aren't setting the :selected option in the right spot.  From your example, it looks like you're setting it in the select helper itself and not in the options.  You'll want to use the :selected in the [options_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select).

For example, this should default to weekly:

```
 <%= f.select :recurr_frequency, options_for_select([["Daily","Daily"], ["Weekly", "Weekly"], ["Monthly","Monthly"]], :selected => "Weekly") %>
```

Comment: Meh... actually looks like your usage is okay on second review. Might be worth trying to set a default in the controller and see if it makes it through after the submit.

Comment: I tried it using options_for_select too and I can't seem to get the default values to show up when the form loads.

Comment: I added an example that works for me.  Give it a try.  If not, what happens when you set @object.recurr_frequency="Daily" in the controller action?